# Custom control sizing/placement issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, custom-controls

I'm trying to create a custom control with C#/WPF. See below for the XAML of my control, and a window I'm trying to put it into.

The problem: When I set the HorizontalAlignment or vertical alignment properties to Center, the upper-left corner of the control is centered, but extends down and to the right. The bounding box of the control as shown in the designer is very small (zero width/heigh I think).

It seems like I have a problem with my control not reporting its size properly when the layout is doing its thing. Also, it doesn't seem to resize when Height and Width are adjusted. I have nothing in the code-behind (yet) that alters the appearance of the control (e.g. no Measure overrides).

This is my first attempt at a custom control - probably better ways of doing it (TextBlock comes to mind), but hey, this is how I learn! :D

The XAML defining my control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="LCD.LiquidCrystalDisplay"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignWidth="300" d:DesignHeight="122">
    <Canvas>

        <Rectangle Fill="#FFD1D1D1" Width="300" Height="122" />
        <Rectangle Fill="#FF345534" Margin="12,8,12,8" Width="276" Height="106" />
        <Rectangle Fill="#FF293E29" Margin="15,11,15,11" Width="270" Height="100" />

        <Line X1="32" X2="32" Y2="111" Y1="11" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FF345534" />
        <Line X1="50" X2="50" Y2="111" Y1="11" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FF345534" />
        <Line X1="67" X2="67" Y2="111" Y1="11" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FF345534" />
        <Line X1="84" X2="84" Y2="111" Y1="11" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FF345534" />
        <Line X1="101" X2="101" Y2="111" Y1="11" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FF345534" />
        <Line X1="117" X2="117" Y2="111" Y1="11" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FF345534" />
        <Line X1="134" X2="134" Y2="111" Y1="11" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FF345534" />
        <Line X1="151" X2="151" Y2="111" Y1="11" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FF345534" />
        <Line X1="168" X2="168" Y2="111" Y1="11" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FF345534" />
        <Line X1="184" X2="184" Y2="111" Y1="11" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FF345534" />
        <Line X1="201" X2="201" Y2="111" Y1="11" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FF345534" />
        <Line X1="218" X2="218" Y2="111" Y1="11" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FF345534" />
        <Line X1="235" X2="235" Y2="111" Y1="11" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FF345534" />
        <Line X1="251" X2="251" Y2="111" Y1="11" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FF345534" />
        <Line X1="268" X2="268" Y2="111" Y1="11" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FF345534" />

        <Line X1="15" X2="285" Y1="36" Y2="36" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FF345534" />
        <Line X1="15" X2="285" Y1="61" Y2="61" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FF345534" />
        <Line X1="15" X2="285" Y1="86" Y2="86" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FF345534" />

    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

And the XAML including it in a window:

```
<Window x:Class="TestJunk.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:LCD;assembly=LCD"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="341" Width="544">
    <Grid Name="MainGrid">
        <my:LiquidCrystalDisplay Name="lcd" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Also, when this control is put into a grid, and the grid's row or column definition has Height or Width set to Auto, it's as if the control's height and width are zero - the Grid's row/column shrink to nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the behaviour of a `Canvas`. Here is what [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx) has to say:

> Canvas is the only panel element that has no inherent layout
>   characteristics. A Canvas has default Height and Width properties of
>   zero, unless it is the child of an element that automatically sizes
>   its child elements. Child elements of a Canvas are never resized, they
>   are just positioned at their designated coordinates. This provides
>   flexibility for situations in which inherent sizing constraints or
>   alignment are not needed or wanted. For cases in which you want child
>   content to be automatically resized and aligned, it is usually best to
>   use a Grid element.

If you want to have the UserControl resize, wrap it around a `Viewbox` and set a `Height` and `Width` to the `Canvas`.